# ¿Cómo puedo convertir objetos de la clase Object a un clase específica creada en el sistema?

Tags: java, conversión-de-tipos

Tengo el siguiente código en un formulario de Búsqueda

```
 Object objeto = listCategoria.getSelectedValue();
 frmCategoriaPaquete cp = new frmCategoriaPaquete();
 cp.busqueda(objeto);
```

Este lo envío a un formulario de ingreso de datos mediante el método búsqueda que posee el siguiente código:

```
 CategoriaPaquete CP =  (CategoriaPaquete) objeto;
 txtDescripcion.setText(CP.getDescripcion());
```

Al momento de convertir el objeto me tira el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to Entidades.CategoriaPaquete
```

Entonces ¿existe alguna manera de convertir un objeto de tipo Object en cualquier objeto de mis clases?

Comment: Tu método `getSelectedValue` al parecer retorna un String. No puedes castear un String  a un Objeto de clase `CategoríaPaquete`

Comment: Intentas castear un String a un Objeto, intenta algo como esto: String cp = objeto;

Comment: Okay, gracias, pero tengo una consulta yo tengo una interfaz con un método de búsqueda que recibe un parámetro de Tipo object y quiero que este se castee según mi clase porque necesito implementarlo en diferentes formularios, en ese caso tengo la interfaz

Comment: Tendrías que tener una clase más genérica y que el objeto que deseas castear herede de esa clase más genérica.

Comment: Copia el código de tu formulario.

Answer (score 1):

En objetos, el cast no hace una "conversión". Lo único que hace el cast es hacer explícito un cambio en el tipo de la referencia.

Si creas un objeto de una instancia, lo puedes asignar a una referencia de una superclase sin especificar el cast:

```
String str = new String("Hola");
Object obj = str;
```

Pero **el objeto creado sigue siendo un String**, sea cual sea el tipo de la referencia.

Si haces una asignación de una referencia/expresión a una subclase, sigues teniendo que asignarlo a una referencia de una clase compatible con la original (esto es, la propia clase de la que es instancia o una superclase/interficie). También debes hacer explícito el cast. Es una forma de decir "estoy seguro que el objeto apuntado por esta referencia es de esta subclase". Continuando el ejemplo:

```
String str1 = obj; // no es valido porque necesita el cast explícito.
String str1 = (String) obj; // es valido porque obj apuntaba a una objeto String.
Integer int1 = (Integer) obj; // fallará porque obj apunta a un String, e Integer no es una superclase de String. No puedes asignar un String a una referencia Integer.
```

Para lo que quieres hacer, tendrás que programar tú un método al que pases un String y que cree una instancia de tu objeto equivalente (para el paso inverso es recomendable implementar `toString()`).

Comment: Muchas gracias intentare hacer lo que me recomiendas

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo para realizar un cast primero debes validar si es un objeto deseado y asi evitas en tiempo de ejecucion el ClassCastException

Ejemplo

```
if( objeto instanceof CategoriaPaquete)
{
    CategoriaPaquete CP =  (CategoriaPaquete) objeto;
    txtDescripcion.setText(CP.getDescripcion());    
}
else
{
    System.out.println("objeto no es una instancia de CategoriaPaquete");
}
```